# How to use Zoomify tile source in openseadragon?

Tags: tile, deepzoom, seadragon, zoomify

I'm trying to figure out how to use tiles generated using Zoomify output from photoshop in an openseadragon project. I gather that I will need to use a custom tile source to do this but the folder structure and file naming convention used by Zoomify is rather puzzling, so I was wondering if anyone had done this before.

I need to configure the getTileUrl function in the custom tile source so that it determines zoom level, row and column for each tile. I have previously used tiles generated with deep zoom composer with no problem (and without the need for a custom tile source), but I'm now using images that are too large for that to be practical eg 15 - 25Gig.

the example in the openseadragon docs is

```
tileSources:   {
        height: 512*256,
        width:  512*256,
        tileSize: 256,
        minLevel: 8,
        getTileUrl: function( level, x, y ){
            return "http://s3.amazonaws.com/com.modestmaps.bluemarble/" +
                    (level-8) + "-r" + x + "-c" + y + ".jpg";
        }
    }
```

but the zoomify folder structure is:
ouput_folder > 
    TileGroup179 > 
       10-100-44.jpg
       10-102-44.jpg
    TileGroup18 >
       8-0-24.jpg
       8-1-24.jpg
       8-10-24.jpg
       ...
    TileGroup180 >

Any help on this would be most appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any documentation on the Zoomify format? That might help. Also, if you just want to process a big image but don't care what format, some of these other options might work: http://openseadragon.github.io/examples/creating-zooming-images/ I'm thinking VIPS may do the trick.

Comment: We tried to use NIP2 which is the GUI version of VIPS but without success, the issue here was file format and size. It would've been great if NIP2 would accept photoshops large image format. The work around involved cutting our image into large tiff files then importing each one into a Deep Zoom Composer project. Re-combining them in the composer then tiling them. The total processing time was a couple of days though on a fastish PC (Intel i7 processor and 32GB RAM, SSD scratch disc etc. I'm thinking there must be a better solution to tiling massive images but for now, job done, move on.

Comment: The main issue was tiling a large image, ultimately the best solution was to avoid the zoomify tile source issue.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it sorted out. It's a shame there still aren't good tools for handling such large files.